# Taking off the top header of a report

Tags: header, abap

I need to make the top header of a report disappear.

The part that I want to take off is in the next image:

[image: image of the report]

Does anyone know how to do it and if it is, I believe it is, possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
REPORT  Z_report
MESSAGE-ID z_message
NO STANDARD PAGE HEADING.
```

The last line is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This top header is called the [standard page header](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstandard_page_header_glosry.htm).

To hide it, add the [`NO STANDARD PAGE HEADING`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapreport_list_options.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_1@1@) option to your `REPORT` line (the first in the program).

For example:

```
REPORT zmyreportprogram NO STANDARD PAGE HEADING.
```